# I can't use backspace and del in textbox (Mozilla)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with textbox validation using JS. This my source:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#letnd").keypress(function(e) {

    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);

    if (!regex.test(key)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });

  $("#letnb").keypress(function(e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="letnd" type="text" name="txtnd" />
<input id="letnb" type="text" name="txtnb" />
```

In other browsers, this code works fine. But why, when I open it in Mozilla, the textbox can't use <kbd>backspace</kbd> and <kbd>del</kbd>?

Comment: Other browsers don't fire `keypress` event when you press backspace or arrows and maybe some other keys, while FF does. Don't know who is right there. If you replace the keypress event to keydown, every browsers will act as FF

Comment: According to [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress) : "The keypress event is traditionally associated with detecting a character value rather than a physical key, and might not be available on all keys in some configurations. ". Also worth to be mentionned that `keypress`event is now deprecated in DOM3. `beforeinput` should be used but is not yet implemented in any major browsers, mostly because specs aren't clear about that. [related chromium bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=342670)

Comment: Thanks Kaiido, but I still do not get the results when i change to keydown. any other solution?because i just only have the textbox is approve latter only.

Comment: check the `input.value` string instead of the keyCode? If there is a forbidden char, then delete it.

Comment: sory, I was new about javascript, so I just got it from google. and whether the string that should I remove?

Comment: I'll post an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#letnd").keydown(function (e) {

        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
        var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);

        console.log(e.keyCode); // check for backspace, delete etc. keyCodes you need

        if (e.keyCode != 8) { // e.g: backspace keyCode for Backspace on OS X
            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and get the idea.

Consider checking (aka regexing) the whole new value of input rather then dealing with single `keypress` or `keydown` / `charCode` or `keyCode`, if possible. You will avoid dealing with different `keyCode`s of same keys on different platforms, deleting, backspacing, Ctrl+R / CMD+R for browser refresh, Ctrl+P / CMD+P for print dialogue, ...

Answer (score 2):

Other browsers don't fire keypress event when you press backspace or arrows and maybe some other keys, while FF does. Don't know who is right there. If you replace the keypress event to keydown, every browsers will act as FF.

According to [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress) :

> The keypress event is traditionally associated with detecting a
>   character value rather than a physical key, and might not be available
>   on all keys in some configurations.

Also worth to be mentionned that `keypressEvent` is now deprecated in DOM3. `beforeinput` should be used but is not yet implemented in any major browsers, mostly because specs aren't clear about that. [related chromium bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=342670).

What you could do however, is to check the value of your `<input>` element on `keyup` and if there is some forbidden chars, remove them. One small caveat is that forbidden char will appear before it's been deleted :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#letnd").keyup(validate);

  $("#letnb").keyup(validate);
});

function validate(e) {

  var regex = new RegExp("[^a-zA-Z]","g");
  var string = this.value;

  var match = string.match(regex);
  if (match) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(regex, '');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="letnd" type="text" name="txtnd" />
<input id="letnb" type="text" name="txtnb" />
```